# React Native GIFs animation run abruptly faster than expected with RN 0.61.x

Tags: react-native, gif

I have recently upgraded the react-native version of an app to 0.61.5 from 0.60.4 and it appears there are some changes to core APIs with respect to GIF animation speed.

I am following up on this thread https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26716. But not luck yet.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any news? i'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi @bdroid please go through the link attached in the question. RN 0.62.2 has got it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to new updates on the same thread attached in the question.
This issue is now resolved with ***RN 0.62.2***